# Sylow $p$-subgroups of rotation group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

I am reading part of a [research paper](https://scholar.rose-hulman.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1326&context=rhumj), which states the following argument.

The paper discusses groups generated by three rotations $a,b,c$, also referred to as a generating triple. In this quote, it argues why groups (generated as described) of order $30$ cannot give a symmetry group.

> By Sylow’s
> theorems, we know that a group of order $30$ must have $1$ or $10$ Sylow-$3$
> subgroups, and $1$ or $6$ Sylow-$5$ subgroups. If we assume that neither of these
> is $1$, then we get that our group has more than $30$ elements. Therefore, one
> of these Sylow subgroups must be normal. However, this would mean the first
> two elements in the generating triple would generate $15$ elements instead of all $30$. Therefore, there is no symmetry group corresponding to this data.

Please may someone clarify the penultimate sentence - why do the first two elements in the generating triple only generate $15$ elements?

Thank you.

Comment: You should told us also that $a$ and $b$ have order $3$ and $5$ in this example. It then follows easily that if $G$ has a normal Sylow $3$- or $5$-subgroup then elements of orders $3$ and $5$ generate a subgroup of order $15$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since (as stated in the paper) $a$ and $b$ have orders $3$ and $5$ respectively, each of them generates a Sylow subgroup. So $H=<a>$ or $K=<b>$ must be a normal subgroup. As a consequence $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $HK=KH$. It follows also that
$$<a,b>=HK=KH$$
since we can rearrange every word made up of $a$ and $b$ in the form $a^i b^j$ (for some $i$, $j$ integers) exploiting the fact that $HK=KH$. We conclude that $<a,b>$ has exactly $3 \cdot 5=15$ elements.

Comment: Thank you! Just as a quick follow-up question, is this possible because $a$ and $b$ have orders which are prime factors of |G| = 30? If $a$ and $b$ had orders $5$ and $6$ for example, this could not occur because $b$ could not generate a Sylow subgroup?

Comment: Well, at least this argument would not work.

Comment: In particular if $o(a)=5$ and $o(b)=6$ then $HK$ is a subset of $<a,b>$ with $30$ distinct elements, so $a$ and $b$ generate the whole group.